# Mediawiki user group for .edu email address?

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

I'm wondering if there's a way to create two different user groups based on their email address: one group for users with .edu email addresses, and another group for non .edu email addresses. I want this to be done automatically upon signup or confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

Try [$wgAutopromote](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgAutopromote) / [AutopromoteCondition](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks/AutopromoteCondition).